# Qt Quick item selection

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I have a question about selecting an item.
I want to create a system.And this system will start like that.
I have two squares and one button.
When I click a button and which square is selected, this square will be moving.

For example, I've selected the first square and I've clicked the button.The first square will be moving.This is a simple question but I want to create without if-else structure.

For example,
When I've selected the first square, program can understand the first square is selected and when I click the button, program will start and which square is selected, this square will move.

Comment: This is actually very simple and there are several ways to do it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: My mind is going to always if-else structure.For example if first square on clicked and button on clicked,first square can move.Like that

Comment: I'd say you don't sound like you have done any QML learning. I suggest you go though some tutorials to understand what the QML paradigm is. At the very least, google `qml keyboard focus`.

Comment: Thank you for helping.I'm new on Qt so I'm trying to understand about QML paradigm.Have a great day !